# Azure DevOps Tasks Condition

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps to build ASP.net project. I am using standard tasks like:

- download nuget
- nuget restore
- build project
- run tests
- publish artifacts

Sometimes we have solution which don't have any unit tests and azure devops gives warning not finding any tests in ui.
[image]

So, is there a way to add condition in build task to only run unit test task only when it can find any test related files in the project.
Here is my yaml file:

```
trigger:
  - main
  - feature/*
  - releases/*
  - bugfix/*
  - hotfix/*

variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
      artifactName: 'drop'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      demands:
          - msbuild
          - visualstudio
          - vstest

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      displayName: Use NuGet      

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: NuGet restore
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: $(solution)

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: Build solution
      inputs:
        solution: $(solution)
        msbuildArgs: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"
        platform: $(buildPlatform)
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: Test Assemblies
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\$(buildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
          !**\obj\**
        platform: $(buildPlatform)
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: Publish Artifact
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: $(artifactName)
        publishLocation: Container
```

Comment: [VSTest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) has `minimumExpectedTests` input argument that's 1 by default. try setting it to 0.

Comment: @qbik that didn't work.